# switch statement with :contains condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

I would like to test if a certain element contains some string in a switch statement. My code is similar to the following:

```
jQuery("#selector").on( "ajaxSuccess", function() {
    var myVar = jQuery(this).is(':contains("some string")');
    switch (myVar){
        case ':contains("some string")': jQuery([do something here]);
        break;
    }
});
```

but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you describe what you need too - you likely do not want a switch statement but we would not know unless you make a [mcve]

Comment: You can only use constants with `case` - so it's looking for the string literal as supplied

Comment: switch statements are optimized to only do equality comparison; you'll have to use if/else to do what you want

Comment: Aside from the obvious syntax problems, why would you need to do this? Your `.is(':contains("some string")')` already enforces the condition, so the `switch` is redundant.

Comment: @mplungjan You are right, I was going to provide some more context but then Jeremy figured it out anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`$(this).text().includes("some string")`

```js
console.log( $("div").text().includes("amet") )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
```